# What does the chime sound while harvesting indicate?

Tags: return-to-popolocrois

In Return to Popolocrois on the 3DS, there's sometimes a chime when harvesting.  What does this mean or indicate?

Answer (score 1):

This means that you have harvested a higher than normal quality item

Fun fact: This feature also came with the Harvest Moon series to Stardew Valley

Comment: How do you typically tell quality?

Comment: It should denote the item with a star or half star